# Using Django to consume an API

Tags: python, django

Can someone point me in the right direction maybe example code?

I have written an **API** in **TastyPie** and I now also want to consume this API within my own Django app. (I want to eat my own Dog food and all that)

**i.e.** I currently list contacts (pure Django) I now want to asynchronous update a record on the page.

before I make a start writing a jquery script that updates a resource on page when a user clicks, I would like to know if there is a more Django way of doing things? for example are there any apps that allow me to use classes? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should try to use the excelent python [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

You have a lot of good and simple examples on the documentation